# How do I add a resource to a bundle using fhirclient (Smart on FHIR)?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, hl7-fhir

I am working with the [fhirclient](http://docs.smarthealthit.org/client-py/index.html) (Smart on FHIR) python library and have successfully created a bundle and individual resources.  I would assume there are helper methods in the "Bundle" class to allow me to add a resource to a bundle but I can't quite seem to figure out how to do this.  For example I have something like (pseudocode):

```
b = fhirclient.Bundle()
p = fhirclient.Patient()
c = fhirclient.Claim()
# Now I want to add my patient (p) and claim (c) to the bundle (b)
```

I thought since the bundle contains the list element "entry" that all I needed to do was append the resource like this:

```
b.entry.append(p)
b.entry.append(c)
```

But that doesn't work.  I get the message: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to create entries using a process like:

```
p_entry = BundleEntry()
p_entry.resource = p
c_entry = BundleEntry()
c_entry.resource = c
b.entry = [p_entry, c_entry]
```

Using `from fhircilent.models.bundle import BundleEntry`

Comment: 1 down for typo on fhirclient, very common with python scientists.